# Переопределение метода в небазового класса

Tags: наследование, классы, c++

Добрый день

Можно ли переопределить метод в классе для которого класс, в котором находится метод не является базовым.

```
class xxx {
public:
...
bool getState() { return x; }
...
};

class yyy {
public:
...
xxx::getState() { return x+1; }
```

Мне не нужно наследовать класс xxx, необходимо лишь изменить реализацию одного метода.

Comment: Для решения какой задачи это может оказаться полезным?

Comment: в классе yyy использую класс xxx как экземпляр класса, но хотел бы переопределить реализацию одного метода

Comment: Можно. С помощью любого текстового редактоа -- берёте и правите описание класса. Если такой подход не устраивает -- мастерите класс-наследник.

Comment: @VladD Наследование, агрегация, is-a... Неизвестному (@Unknown) зачем-то нужна перегрузка метода, если я правильно понял (желание достаточно странное, но если хочется, можно и обфускатором пройтись)

Comment: @alexlz: Ну да. Ему нужен класс, в котором все методы такие, как в исходном классе, а один не такой. То есть повторное использование кода. Для этого надо использовать не наследование, а агрегацию. (Чтобы потом не ругаться на ООП, надо применять его правильно.)

Comment: А по мне так чел хочет просто хакнуть другой класс, переопределив его методы насильно извне. Типа есть какой-то системный вызов SomeClass.someMethod(), а он хочет чтобы автоматом вызывался его метод ИМХО. Других объяснений не нахожу.
Если я прав, то вам нужно рыть в сторону перехвата вызовов ф-й, а это явно выходит за рамки обычного программирования.

Comment: @MDJHD: Ну, имеет право хотеть. Поскольку язык официально такого сервиса не предоставляет, имеет право не получиться.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно сделать Декоратор (https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator). Тогда наследоваться не нужно, и прямые вызовы будут адресованы классу-делегату, а переопределённые, будут реализованы в декораторе.

Один момент - этот вариант подойдет, если нет необходимости иметь доступ к внутренней реализации докорируемого класса (private / protected полям/методам).